# Realm authentication for an app with thousands users

Tags: authentication, realm, realm-object-server

I'm using Realm Object Server, every user has his own database. What is the proper way to do authentication when you have thousands of users?

Comment: What do you mean? You just use the `SyncUser.login()` methods for the users you want to login? I don't assume each open app wants to login thousands of users, but just the user using the app?

Comment: Yes, it's what I was looking for. I will register every single user. Thank you very much.